# Why Does Table-Cell Border Not have Corners?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm experiencing some strangeness while adding a thick border to a table-cell.

Why aren't there corners?

```
<fo:table-cell border-color="{$moonyellow}"
               border-style="solid"
               border-width="0.7em">
    <fo:block padding="2mm" text-align="center">
        <xsl:value-of select="./value" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

[image: Cornerless border]

I'm using FOP 2.1

Comment: I'm using version 2.1

Comment: Many products draw borders in the PDF using a line when they should be a polygon with cut/mitered corners. You get what you get with the product you select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the 'notches' are likely from/for the borders of the diagonal-corner cells.

Try `<fo:table border-collapse="separate">` to use the 'separated borders model' (if FOP supports it). See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#border-collapse and https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html#propdef-border-collapse